# Google bigquery api not listing historical jobs

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, gcloud, google-apis-explorer

Any idea why the jobs.list() returning just today's jobs ? If I print the variable t it only provides me the jobs that ran today. What should I do to get some more history, say 90 days?

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
# Construct the service object for interacting with the BigQuery API.
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)


t=bigquery_service.jobs().list(projectId=project_id,allUsers=True,
projection='full',stateFilter=job_state.lower()).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are not iterating over page results. Adapt your code to something like:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
results = []

t=service.jobs().list(projectId=project_id,allUsers=True,
    projection='full',stateFilter=job_state.lower()).execute()
results.append(t['jobs'])

while t.get('nextPageToken') is not None:
        t=service.jobs().list(projectId=project_id,
                              allUsers=True,
                              projection='full',
                              stateFilter=job_state.lower(),
                              pageToken=t.get("nextPageToken")).execute()
    if t.get('jobs'):
        results.append(t['jobs'])
```

This should iterate over pages using `pageToken` and append the response to `results`.

You could also use the python [google-cloud-api](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) where those operations are already handled automatically for you (but it will not work on AppEngine Standard environment in case you are using it).